# Getting error for db query when nginx and db on different servers? "PHP message: Database transaction aborted automatically in"

Tags: php, mysql, nginx, runtime-error, moodle

My client was having one old server with apache, mysql, php. We moved server to new location and I installed easy engine on it. we have separate machine for db server and http (nginx)+php server. All other things going good. Issue is with moodle portal.

https://example.com/elearning/

I am getting error while running moodle on new server. Below is error coming at runtime for moodle, while attempting quiz, creating new course. I googled for suggestions but nothing worked. I think there is something which blocking query request. On old server it was working really fine. I dont know whether it is issue with nginx or with separate db server.

1........................................... with moodle

```
2015/04/27 09:04:34 [error] 28691#0: *5473 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: Database transaction aborted automatically in /var/www/example.com/htdocs/elearning/course/togglecompletion.php" while reading response header from upstream, client: 49.32.0.158, server: intellipaat.com, request: "POST /elearning/course/togglecompletion.php HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "example.com", referrer: "https://example.com/elearning/course/view.php?id=248"
```

2..............................with wordpress.... i have db prefix for wordpress is **ip_**

```
Apr 27, 07:59:48    WordPress database error Table 'example_com.wp_posts' doesn't exist for query SELECT count(*) AS count FROM wp_posts WHERE `post_type` = 'wpcf7_contact_form' made by require_once('wp-admin/admin.php'), require('wp-admin/menu.php'), require_once('wp-admin/includes/menu.php'), do_action('admin_menu'), call_user_func_array, postaffiliatepro->addPrimaryConfigMenu, postaffiliatepro_Util_ContactForm7Helper::formsExists, postaffiliatepro_Util_ContactForm7Helper::formsExistsNew, W3_Db->query, W3_DbCache->query, W3_DbCallUnderlying->query, W3_Db->query, W3_DbProcessor->query, W3_Db->default_query
```

Answer (score 0):

It **might** be because the database is using MyISAM instead of InnoDB.

There is a tool in Moodle for converting the tables here

`/admin/tool/innodb/`

Obviously back up the database before trying anything though.

If the tool isn't available then comment which version of Moodle you are using. You can check that in /version.php or by going to site admin -> notifications.

Comment: All table are having innodb engine already. Moodle ver 2.5+ (Build: 20130530)

Comment: I converted all tables to MyISAM and issue which I was facing with moodle is fixed now. Quiz started to work.

Comment: Weird :) the other way around then, glad its working okay though.